# Binding property PropertyChange with command that implements ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am implementing MVVM pattern in wpf application. We have a textbox that calls event handler on KeyUp event. I binded text of that textbox with property tb_property which is in ViewModel. The idea that I have is to have ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChange and to bind command object that does what event handler did and implements ICommand to the change on that tb_property. Is this a good idea, and how should I do it? I am trying to get rid of most of the events from View. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, depending on what MVVM framework you are using you can bind the control's event to a iCommand on the viewmodel.

I use MVVM light so they have a build in realaycommand for just such a condition.  I then bind the control's event int he following way:

add the following to your usercontrol/window opening tag (the cmd uses the mvvm framworks implementation of icommand):

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

Then I add the command binding to the control like:

```
<TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding tb_property, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="YourEvent">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding YourCommandPropertyOnVIewModel}" CommandParameter="OptionalCommandParameter"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TextBox>
```

This way you move all your "event" to your view model and I love this because other controls can use the same command.

Hope this helps

JK

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!